# Did snap just killed my Firefox?

Tags: firefox, snap

I had some tabs open in Firefox, when I decided to use Chrome to watch a video on YT*. Suddenly, the quality of the video tanks, and of course it's becuse snap is updating, and I have to find something else to do for a minute or so. When I come back to the computer, Firefox is closed, no warnings about closing open tabs, nothing. Did snap just killed the Firefox process to update something?

(*) I am logged to Google on Chrome but not on Firefox, so Chrome tracks the videos that I watched.

Comment: Review your logs around that time for clues. Maybe something else happened.

Comment: I doubt it would really matter. Just open Firefox back up again when it is done.

Comment: Could be a bug indeed if you can reproduce this in the future.